# How to capture the entire output and exit status code of a step in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I'm familiar on how to get a [simple output](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs) for a step in GitHub Actions. But how can I run a command in a step, capture the entire `stdout` to be used in another step, without intercepting the exit status code of the command?

Suppose that I want to execute this bash script and capture the output:

mimick-output.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Output 1..."
sleep 1
echo "Output 2..."
sleep 1
echo "Output 3..."
sleep 1
exit 123
```

I've tried capturing the output in two ways, both of which unsuccessful:

Approach 1:

```yaml
- name: Produce Some Output
  id: run-produce-output
  run: echo $(foo_output=./mimick-output.sh) >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
- name: Echo output
  run: echo ${{ steps.run-produce-output.outputs.foo_output }}
```

[image: get output of command in github actions]

Approach 2:

```yaml
- name: Produce output.
  id: run-produce-output
  run: ./mimick-output.sh
- name: Echo output
  if: always()
  run: echo ${{join(steps.run-produce-output.outputs.*, '\n')}}
```

[image: capture github actions step command output]

In both scenarios, `${{ steps.run-produce-output.outputs.foo_output }}` is empty.

I would expect that it printed:

```
Output 1...
Output 2...
Output 3...
```

And that the exit status code of `run-produce-output` was 123.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, although I suspect there are better ways to go about it.

This was my solution, after all:

```
- name: Produce Some Output
  run: ./bin/mimick-output.sh > output.txt
- name: Echo output
  if: always()
  run: cat output.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you want to always capture the logs even if the command/script fails, right?

Comment: @Azeem That's correct.

Comment: Right. IMO, this approach is fine. You could modify your approach # 1 to `echo "foo_output="$(./mimick-output.sh)"" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` but then you'll have to take care of newlines and formatting.